# Gps doesn't work on Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I  work an application which return a position of the user and it gets information from GPS.
and send position to email  Following code is there, it is working perfectly on Android 2.3 but on Android 4.2.2 it doesn't work. on Android 4.2.2 device and emulator doesn't work. This
code for GPS Tracker:

```
package com.example.safetymobile;

//package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager .NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

GPS :

```
package com.example.safetymobile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;


public class GPS extends Activity {
    String NotifyWay="";
    CheckBox chk,chk1;
    EditText edt,edt1;
    Button btn;
    GPSTracker gps;
    public int time = 0;
    public Timer t = new Timer();
    int interval = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    int counterend = 2;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
    Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
    Date stopt = cal.getTime();
    int StopTime = 0;





    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a"); 

        //chk=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.notiEmail);
        //chk1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.notisms);

        edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.interval);
        edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeStop);
        //email 
        /*chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(NotifyWay.equals(""))
                {
                    NotifyWay="Email";
                }
                else
                {
                    NotifyWay="Email";
                    chk1.setChecked(false);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can choose one way only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });*/

        /*chk1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(NotifyWay.equals(""))
                {
                    NotifyWay="SMS";
                }
                else
                {
                    NotifyWay="SMS";
                    chk.setChecked(false);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can choose one way only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });*/
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DoneAdd);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int val=Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());
                StopTime=Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
                interval=val*60000;

                SQLiteDatabase db;                      
                db = openOrCreateDatabase("Saftey.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                db.setVersion(1);
                db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                final String CREATE_TABLE_setting = 
                        "CREATE TABLE GPS ("
                        + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + "valTime INTEGER,"
                        + "stopTime INTEGER);";
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_setting);
                ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
                values1.put("valTime", interval);
                values1.put("stopTime", StopTime);
                db.insert("Setting", null, values1);
                //Convert Minute To Milliseconds
                stopt.setHours(currentLocalTime.getHours() + StopTime);

                tt();


                Intent intent = new Intent(GPS.this, Change_setting.class);
                startActivity(intent);




            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gps, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void tt()
    {
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                        //// .....
                        if(currentLocalTime.compareTo(stopt) > 0)

                        {
                            t.cancel();
                        }
                        else
                             Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "d < d1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        gps = new GPSTracker(GPS.this);

                        // check if GPS enabled     
                        if(gps.canGetLocation())
                        {

                            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                            String text ="https://Maps.google.com/maps?q=" + Double.toString(latitude) + "," + Double.toString(longitude)  ;// latitude
                          //............................

                             String em="";
                             //String pn="";
                             //SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
                             //SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                             //String pn= pref.getString("PhNum", null);
                             //edit.commit();
                             SQLiteDatabase db;

                             db = openOrCreateDatabase(
                                    "Saftey.db"
                                    , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
                                    , null
                                    );
                             db.setVersion(1);
                             db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                             db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                             Cursor cur = db.query("info", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                             cur.moveToFirst();
                             while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) 
                             {
                                 //pn = cur.getString(0);
                                 em=cur.getString(3);
                                 cur.moveToNext();
                             }
                             cur.close();
                            // if(NotifyWay.equals("Email"))
                           //  {
                                 SendingEmail(em, text);
                           //  }
                            /* else
                             {
                                 if(NotifyWay.equals("SMS"))
                                 {
                                     SendingSMS(pn, text);
                                 }

                             }*/




                              //......................
                        }
                       else{
                            // can't get location
                            // GPS or Network is not enabled
                            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }

                        //// .....
                        time += 1;
                    }

                });
            }

        }, 0, interval);
    }



    public void SendingEmail(String em, String text)
    {
         Mail m = new Mail("mbrm.yu@gmail.com", "mbrm_yu123"); 
          String[] toArr = {em}; 
          m.setTo(toArr); 
          m.setFrom("mbrm.yu@gmail.com"); 
          m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
          //m.setBody("I'm in Danger Dad, please Help ...");
          m.setBody(text);
          try 
          { 
            //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

            if(m.send()) { 
              Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
          } 
          catch(Exception e) 
          { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "There was a problem sending the email to : " + em, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
          } 
    }


    /*public void SendingSMS(String pn, String text)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(pn, null, text, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }*/

}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.safetymobile"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.ContactList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.Change_setting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_setting"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.CallContent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call_content"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.SMS"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sms"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.Alication_list"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alication_list"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.Apps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apps" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.Pass"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pass" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.ChangePass"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_pass" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.GPS"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gps" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.safetymobile.LightActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_light"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".StartupActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please any help?

Answer (score 0):

[getting address in android using web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701535/getting-address-in-android-using-web-service)

See the answer i have posted. my code works fine, but in android version 4.0 and above, you have to manually open GPS. You can not open it programmatically

Comment: but can't run on emulator or  device

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some trouble and just use [Google Play Services Locations API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). They provide a good implementation and precise location if you have Play Services installed on your device (most of devices do now)