# getting address in android using web service

Tags: android, web-services, geolocation, street-address

iam new to android development.

i have tried to get location address using web service but i got class not found exception  when i lunched  this code.if any one could please suggest me proper solution for this..

code for service class....

```
public class MWService extends Service implements LocationListener {


private LocationManager myLocationManager;
private LocationProvider myLocationProvider;
private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
private long frequency;
private double total_distance = 0;
private Location currentLocation;
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.motorvehicle.android";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
private GeocoderHelper geocoder  = new GeocoderHelper();
private boolean isStart=true;
private Location startLocation,endLocation;
private String startAddress="";
private String endAddress="";
private JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
private boolean isInternet;
//private final Handler handler = new Handler();

public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
    try {
        System.out.println("latitude current :"+currentLocation.getLatitude());
        System.out.println("latitude current :"+currentLocation.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("latitude new  :"+newLocation.getLatitude());
        System.out.println("latitude new  :"+newLocation.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("distance total :"+total_distance);
        //System.out.println(distance(22.306813, 73.180239,22.301016, 73.177986, 'K') + " Kilometers\n");
        double diff = 0.0;
        diff = currentLocation.getLatitude()- newLocation.getLatitude();
        System.out.println("difference ::"+diff);
        if(diff != 0){
            total_distance = total_distance + currentLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);
        }


        if(isStart){
            isStart = false;
            startLocation = newLocation;
        /*  if(InternetAvailable()){
                //startAddress =    geocoder.fetchCityName(getApplicationContext(),newLocation);
                System.out.println("start address:"+startAddress);
            }*/

        }else{
            endLocation = newLocation;
            /*if(InternetAvailable()){
                //endAddress =  geocoder.fetchCityName(getApplicationContext(),newLocation);
                System.out.println("endAddress :"+endAddress);
            }*/
        }

        currentLocation = newLocation;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentLocation = newLocation;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean InternetAvailable() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // while(isStopMe){
            System.out.println("This is inside ................. :");
            try {
                if (!checkConnection()) {
                    System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");
                    isInternet = false;
                    System.out.println("First");
                } else {
                    if (inetAddr()) {
                        System.out.println("Net Connectivity is Present");
                        isInternet = true;
                        System.out.println("Second");
                    } else {
                        if (mobileConnect()) {
                            System.out.println("THIRD");
                            if (inetAddr()) {
                                System.out
                                        .println("Net Connectivity is Present");
                                isInternet = true;
                                System.out.println("FOURTH");
                            } else {
                                System.out
                                        .println("No Internet Connectivity");
                            isInternet = false;
                                System.out.println("FIFTH");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");
                            isInternet = false;
                            System.out.println("SIX");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Leak ko catch");
            }

        }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isInternet;
}


public boolean checkConnection() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if ((ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || ni
                    .getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    & ni.isConnected() & ni.isAvailable()) {
                connected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return connected;
}

public boolean inetAddr() {
    boolean x1 = false;

    try {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("ntp-nist.ldsbc.edu",37),3000);
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
            x1 = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        x1 = false;

    }
    return x1;
}
public boolean mobileConnect() {
    boolean conn = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNet = cm
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (activeNet != null) {
        conn = true;
    } else {
        conn = false;
    }
    return conn;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void myNotify(String text) {
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text, System
            .currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "MotorVehicleApp", text, contentIntent);
    // notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    myNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notif);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


     String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }


    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    android.util.Log.d("MWD", "creating");
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("location manager:"+myLocationManager.getAllProviders());
    myLocationProvider = myLocationManager.getProvider("gps");
    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    updatePreferences();



    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:"+startAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } });
}
public void updatePreferences() {
    // sync local variables with preferences
    android.util.Log.d("NWD", "updating preferences");
    frequency = 10;
    // update the LM with the new frequency
    myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(myLocationProvider.getName(),frequency, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    /////------set edittext editable        

     android.util.Log.d("NWD", "destroying");

     System.out.println("Inside on destroy of MWService");
     myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //myNotify("stopping");

    InsertTripDetails_AsyncTask insert = new InsertTripDetails_AsyncTask();
    insert.execute();

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    android.util.Log.d("NWD", "starting");
    currentLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(myLocationProvider.getName());
    //myNotify("starting"); 

    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 3000); // 1 sec

}
private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("total_distance::"+total_distance);
            intent.putExtra("distance",(total_distance/1000));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
 };

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null; // this is for heavy IPC, not used
}
private class InsertTripDetails_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {


                try {
                    //InternetAvailable()
                    if(InternetAvailable()){
                        startAddress =  geocoder.fetchCityName(getApplicationContext(),startLocation);
                        System.out.println("start address:"+startAddress);
                        endAddress = geocoder.fetchCityName(getApplicationContext(),endLocation);
                        System.out.println("end address:"+endAddress);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("internet not available");
                    }

                    // Internet not available when data are store in latitude and longitute format
                    if(startAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("") && endAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        DecimalFormat sd = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                        System.out.println("1 lat:"+sd.format(startLocation.getLatitude()) +" long:"+sd.format(startLocation.getLongitude())+",lat:"+sd.format(endLocation.getLatitude()) +" long:"+sd.format(endLocation.getLongitude()));

                    }else if(startAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        DecimalFormat sd = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                        System.out.println("2 lat:"+sd.format(startLocation.getLatitude()) +" long:"+sd.format(startLocation.getLongitude())+","+endAddress);

                    }else if(endAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        DecimalFormat sd = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                        try {
                            System.out.println(startAddress+",3 lat:"+sd.format(endLocation.getLatitude()) +" long:"+sd.format(endLocation.getLongitude()));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(startAddress+" "+ endAddress);
                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }



                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("In catch of webservice thus no internet");

                }


        return "dfs";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            }
}

}
```

code for geocoder class

```
public class GeocoderHelper
{
private static final AndroidHttpClient ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(GeocoderHelper.class.getName());

private String address="";
private Location i_Location;
private Context i_Context;
public String fetchCityName(final Context contex, final Location location)
{
    i_Location = location;
    i_Context = contex;
  try {
        return new Address().execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return address;

    } 
}



public class Address extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{



    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String cityName = null;

        if (Geocoder.isPresent())
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("location latitude is"+i_Location.getLatitude());
                System.out.println("location longitude is"+i_Location.getLongitude());

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(i_Context, Locale.getDefault());
                List<android.location.Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(i_Location.getLatitude(), i_Location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                    //cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    address = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    System.out.println("geocoder inside present address is"+address);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignored)
            {
                // after a while, Geocoder start to trhow "Service not availalbe" exception. really weird since it was working before (same device, same Android version etc..
            }
        }

        if (cityName != null) // i.e., Geocoder succeed
        {
            return cityName;
        }
        else // i.e., Geocoder failed
        {
            return fetchCityNameUsingGoogleMap();
        }

    }

    // Geocoder failed :-(
    // Our B Plan : Google Map
    private String fetchCityNameUsingGoogleMap()
    {


        try
        {
            String googleMapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + i_Location.getLatitude() + ","
                    + i_Location.getLongitude() + "&sensor=false&language=fr";

            JSONObject googleMapResponse = new JSONObject(ANDROID_HTTP_CLIENT.execute(new HttpGet(googleMapUrl),
                    new BasicResponseHandler()));

            // many nested loops.. not great -> use expression instead
            // loop among all results
            JSONArray results = (JSONArray) googleMapResponse.get("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
            {
                // loop among all addresses within this result
                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                address = result.getString("formatted_address");
                System.out.println("map address:"+address);
                break;

      /*          if (result.has("address_components"))
                {
                    JSONArray addressComponents = result.getJSONArray("address_components");
                    // loop among all address component to find a 'locality' or 'sublocality'
                    for (int j = 0; j < addressComponents.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject addressComponent = addressComponents.getJSONObject(j);
                        if (result.has("types"))
                        {
                            JSONArray types = addressComponent.getJSONArray("types");

                            // search for locality and sublocality
                            String cityName = null;
                            String ROUTE= null;

                            for (int k = 0; k < types.length(); k++)
                            {

                                if ("locality".equals(types.getString(k)) && cityName == null)
                                {
                                    if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                    {
                                        cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                    }
                                    else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                    {
                                        cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                    }
                                }
                                if ("sublocality".equals(types.getString(k)))
                                {
                                    if (addressComponent.has("long_name"))
                                    {
                                        cityName = addressComponent.getString("long_name");
                                    }
                                    else if (addressComponent.has("short_name"))
                                    {
                                        cityName = addressComponent.getString("short_name");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (cityName != null)
                            {
                                address = cityName;
                                return cityName;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }*/
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
        return address;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

          super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

code for MAinActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MWService.class));



}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MWService.class));
}

}
```

i have use permission in my menifest file for both internet and AccessFineLocation

my logcat msg.....

```
10-31 13:40:41.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.address2/com.example.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.address2-1.apk]
10-31 13:40:41.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.address2-1.apk]
```

code for my menifest file....

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="MWService"></service>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: Did you declare you activity in your manifest?

Comment: i have added my menifest here